# Why is codeigniter outputting whitespace in source code?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter to output XML code. The issue that I am facing is that Codeigniter outputs 1 line of white space on the first line only when I view the source, and prevents my xml response from parsing.

I realized that this white space comes after I invoke the parent construct.

```
parent::__construct();
```

Has anyone had this issue before? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was autoloading a library, and in one of the files the `<?php` opening tag started in the second line.

Wow took me 4 hours to figure it out.